# Updating calendar in C# not working as intended

Tags: c#

```
public int CourseUpdate(string uCourse_Code, string uCourse_Name, string uCourse_Description,       DateTime uCourse_Start_Date, DateTime uCourse_End_Date, string uClass_Size)
    {
        string queryStr = "UPDATE Course SET" +
            " Course_Name = @Course_Name, " +
            " Course_Description = @Course_Description, " +
            " Course_Start_Date = @Course_Start_Date, " +
            " Course_End_Date = @Course_End_Date," +
            " Class_Size = @Class_Size" +
            " WHERE Course_Code = @Course_Code";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_Name", uCourse_Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_Description", uCourse_Description);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_Start_Date", uCourse_Start_Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_End_Date", uCourse_End_Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class_Size", uClass_Size);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course_Code", uCourse_Code);

        conn.Open();
        int nofRow = 0;
        nofRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

        return nofRow;
    }


protected void gvCourse_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //int result = 0;
        //Course XYZ = new Course();
        //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvCourse.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //string id = gvCourse.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        //string UCourse_Code = ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
        //string UCourse_Name = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
        //string UCourse_Description = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
        //string UCourse_Start_Date = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
        //string UCourse_End_Date = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
        //string UClass_Size = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;

        //result = XYZ.CourseUpdate(UCourse_Code, UCourse_Name, UCourse_Description,    UCourse_Start_Date, UCourse_End_Date, UClass_Size);
        //if (result > 0)
        //{
            //Response.Write("<script>alert('Product updated successfully');</script>");
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //Response.Write("<script>alert('Product NOT updated');</script>");
        //}
        //gvCourse.EditIndex = -1;
        //bind();
    }

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CourseView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testrun.CourseView" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <h1>Courses</h1>
<asp:GridView ID="gvCourse" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Course_Code" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCourse_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvCourse_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvCourse_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvCourse_RowUpdating" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course_Code" HeaderText="Course Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course_Name" HeaderText="Course Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course_Description" HeaderText="Course Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course_Start_Date" HeaderText="Course Start Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course_End_Date" HeaderText="Course End Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Class_Size" HeaderText="Class Size" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" ShowDeleteButton="True"  ShowEditButton="False" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#5D7B9D" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" BorderColor="#F7F6F3" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
```

</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btn_AddCourse" runat="server" Text="Add Course" OnClick="btn_AddCourse_Click" />
</asp:Content>

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course] (
[Course_Code]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Course_Name]        VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Course_Description] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Course_Start_Date]  DATETIME      NULL,
[Course_End_Date]    DATETIME      NULL,
[Class_Size]         VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Course_Code] ASC),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Course_Code] ASC)
);
```

When i tried to update the calender fields or any other fields after I'm able to retrieve it from mySQL Server, it keeps telling me that my course is not updated. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).